# Registro de varios datos del mismo tipo en un solo registro enlazado a php con relación de tablas de mysql

Tags: php, html

Buenas soy algo novato en la programación y estoy dudoso con respecto a como hacer lo siguiente, tengo un sistema en php enlazado a mysql.

tengo un registro hecho en php que me manda los datos a una tabla llamada 'estudiantes' el cual tiene:

```
estudiantes
-------------
cedula(key),
apellido,
nombre,
carrera, 
turno, 
seccion, 
email.
```

y quiero hacer de la misma manera un registro de: `grupos`

pero para registrar un grupo de estudiantes quiero que me pida:

```
ID_grupo(key) AUTO_INCREMENT, 
proyecto, 
cod_parroquia, 
lugar, 
habitantes, 
cod_periodo.
```

Esos serían datos que me den información del grupo, una vez que se esos datos los llene el usuario:

1. El sistema me debe pedir cuántos estudiantes hay en el grupo.
2. Dependiendo de cuántos hayan, se abrirán tantas cajas de texto en html para ingresar nada más que la cédula.

Y a través de eso me debe tomar en cuenta todos los datos ingresados en la tabla 'estudiantes' ejemplo: el grupo `ID_grupo=00001` tiene 4 estudiantes, me muestra (todos los datos de información de grupo) y a la vez todos los datos de la tabla 'estudiantes' de esos 4 que ingrese en mi sistema para que se registraran junto con ese `ID_grupo` que sería mi campo clave.

Agradezco mucho cualquier consejo, ejemplos, estructura de código, pero lo que más me confunde es como queda la base de datos con eso, las tablas y los campos, no sé como ingresar varios datos del mismo tipo en un mismo registro

acá el código:

```
<?php
include ('control.php');
$boton= $_POST['boton'];
$idgrupo= $_POST['idgrupo'];
$num_int= $_POST['num_int'];
$ced_alum= $_POST['ced_alum'];
$op= $_POST['op'];
if ($boton=="Guardar") {
    $sql="insert into grupo ()
    values ('')";
    if (mysql_query($sql)) {
        echo "<script> alert ('Data Almacenda')</script>";
        echo "<script> window.location='registro.php'</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script> alert ('No Guardado')</script>";
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registro de grupos</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">

<h1>Creacion del Grupo:</h1> 
<p><label>Grupo Nro:</label> <input type="text" name="idgrupo" readonly placeholder="Número predeterminado"></p>

<p>
    <label>Carrera:</label>
    <select name="carrera" required="">
    <option>Seleccionar</option>
    <option>Administración agropecuaria</option>
    <option>Administración de empresas</option>
    <option>Gastronomía</option>
    <option>Informática</option>
    <option>Turismo</option>    
    </select>
</p>

<p>
    <label>Turno</label>
    <select name="turno">
    <option>Seleccionar</option>
    <option>Matutino</option>
    <option>Vepertino</option>
    <option>Sabatino</option>   
    </select>
</p>

<p>
    <label>Período académico:</label><input type="text" name="periodo" placeholder="(I-2000)(II-2000)(III-2000)">
</p>
<p><label><h1>Integrantes:</h1></label></p>
<p><label>Numero de integrantes:</label><input type="number" name="op"></p>
<?php
switch ($op) {
    case 1:
        // se deben abrir tantas cajas de texto para registro como numeros se ingresen en "Numero de integrantes"
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
?>
# Estás son las cajas de texto que se deben abrir dependiendo de cuantos numeros sean los integrantes, de modo que se ingrese la cedula y ya me tome en cuenta todos los datos ya ingresados en la tabla estudiantes
<p>
<label>Cédula: </label><input type="text" name="ced_alumno">
</p>

<p>
<label>Cédula: </label><input type="text" name="ced_alumno">
</p>

<p>
<label>Cédula: </label><input type="text" name="ced_alumno">
</p>

<p>
<label>Cédula: </label><input type="text" name="ced_alumno">
</p>

<p>
<label>Cédula: </label><input type="text" name="ced_alumno">
</p>

<p>
<label>Cédula: </label><input type="text" name="ced_alumno">
</p>

<p><input type="submit" name="boton" value="Guardar"></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="boton" value="Limpiar"></p>
<p><a href="http://localhost/sercom/menu3.php">Volver</a></p>
   </p>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido brother, te recomiendo que revises https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas cómo funciona el sitio, por otro lado, seré breve: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: el registro de estudiantes está tal como lo quiero, pero en el registro de grupo no sé como hacerlo, y no sé como afecta a la tabla grupo y a sus respectivos campos para que se relacione con la de estudiantes

Comment: coloca el código de lo que has hecho :D así la comunidad sabe que tienes interés en resolverlo y con gusto te damos una mano, porque tal y como está suena a "ayuda, haz mi tarea". Por otro lado, revisa el enlace que te comenté antes, es muy importante :D

Comment: ahí puse el código editando la pregunta, veo que esta página lee el código y no lo muestra en forma de texto, está escasamente trabajado ya que no se me ocurren ideas de como hacerlo como lo describo

Comment: cuando insertes código en las preguntas, asegúrate seleccionar todo el código y presionar: control+k. Así se formatea y queda tal y como ves ahora :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He aquí como lo resolví, el problema era una duplicidad de variables las cuales no veía como organizarlas, por si a alguno le sucede que quieren hacer varios registros del mismo tipo y que se guarden con un código que quieran ingresar una sola vez:

```
<?php
include ('control.php');
$boton= $_POST['boton'];
$idgrupo= $_POST['idgrupo'];
$carrera= $_POST['carrera'];
$periodo= $_POST['periodo'];
//------ 1
$boton1= $_POST['boton1'];
$ced_alum= $_POST['ced_alum'];
$nom= $_POST['nom'];
$ape= $_POST['ape'];
$turno= $_POST['turno'];
//------ 2
$boton2= $_POST['boton2'];
$ced_alum2= $_POST['ced_alum2'];
$nom2= $_POST['nom2'];
$ape2= $_POST['ape2'];
$turno2= $_POST['turno2'];
//------ 3
$boton3= $_POST['boton3'];
$ced_alum3= $_POST['ced_alum3'];
$nom3= $_POST['nom3'];
$ape3= $_POST['ape3'];
$turno3= $_POST['turno3'];
//------ 4
$boton4= $_POST['boton4'];
$ced_alum4= $_POST['ced_alum4'];
$nom4= $_POST['nom4'];
$ape4= $_POST['ape4'];
$turno4= $_POST['turno4'];
//------ 5
$boton5= $_POST['boton5'];
$ced_alum5= $_POST['ced_alum5'];
$nom5= $_POST['nom5'];
$ape5= $_POST['ape5'];
$turno5= $_POST['turno5'];
//------ 6
$boton6= $_POST['boton6'];
$ced_alum6= $_POST['ced_alum6'];
$nom6= $_POST['nom6'];
$ape6= $_POST['ape6'];
$turno6= $_POST['turno6'];
$op= $_POST['op'];


// Buscar alumno 1
if ($boton1=="Buscar") {
    # code...
    $sql="Select * from alumno where ced_alum ='$ced_alum'";
    $busqueda=mysql_query($sql);
    if($registro=mysql_fetch_array($busqueda)){
        $ced_alum = $registro['ced_alum'];
        $nom = $registro['nom'];
        $ape = $registro['ape'];
        $turno = $registro['turno'];

            }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Registro No existe en el Sistema')</script>";
        }
}
// Cierre Alumno 1

// Buscar alumno 2
if ($boton2=="Buscar") {
    # code...
    $sql="Select * from alumno where ced_alum ='$ced_alum2'";
    $busqueda=mysql_query($sql);
    if($registro=mysql_fetch_array($busqueda)){
        $ced_alum2 = $registro['ced_alum'];
        $nom2 = $registro['nom'];
        $ape2 = $registro['ape'];
        $turno2 = $registro['turno'];

            }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Registro No existe en el Sistema')</script>";
        }
}
// Cierre Alumno 2

// Buscar alumno 3
if ($boton3=="Buscar") {
    # code...
    $sql="Select * from alumno where ced_alum ='$ced_alum3'";
    $busqueda=mysql_query($sql);
    if($registro=mysql_fetch_array($busqueda)){
        $ced_alum3 = $registro['ced_alum'];
        $nom3 = $registro['nom'];
        $ape3 = $registro['ape'];
        $turno3 = $registro['turno'];

            }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Registro No existe en el Sistema')</script>";
        }
}
// Cierre Alumno 3

// Buscar alumno 4
if ($boton3=="Buscar") {
    # code...
    $sql="Select * from alumno where ced_alum ='$ced_alum4'";
    $busqueda=mysql_query($sql);
    if($registro=mysql_fetch_array($busqueda)){
        $ced_alum4 = $registro['ced_alum'];
        $nom4 = $registro['nom'];
        $ape4 = $registro['ape'];
        $turno4 = $registro['turno'];

            }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Registro No existe en el Sistema')</script>";
        }
}
// Cierre Alumno 4

// Buscar alumno 5
if ($boton3=="Buscar") {
    # code...
    $sql="Select * from alumno where ced_alum ='$ced_alum5'";
    $busqueda=mysql_query($sql);
    if($registro=mysql_fetch_array($busqueda)){
        $ced_alum5 = $registro['ced_alum'];
        $nom5 = $registro['nom'];
        $ape5 = $registro['ape'];
        $turno5 = $registro['turno'];

            }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Registro No existe en el Sistema')</script>";
        }
}
// Cierre Alumno 5

// Buscar alumno 6
if ($boton6=="Buscar") {
    # code...
    $sql="Select * from alumno where ced_alum ='$ced_alum6'";
    $busqueda=mysql_query($sql);
    if($registro=mysql_fetch_array($busqueda)){
        $ced_alum6 = $registro['ced_alum'];
        $nom6 = $registro['nom'];
        $ape6 = $registro['ape'];
        $turno6 = $registro['turno'];

            }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Registro No existe en el Sistema')</script>";
        }
}
// Cierre Alumno 6
if ($boton=="Guardar") {

    $sql="insert into grupo values (null, $idgrupo, '$ced_alum', '$nom', '$ape', '$turno')";
        mysql_query($sql);
    $sql2="insert into grupo values (null, $idgrupo, '$ced_alum2', '$nom2', '$ape2', '$turno2')";
        mysql_query($sql2); 
    $sql3="insert into grupo values (null, $idgrupo, '$ced_alum3', '$nom3', '$ape3', '$turno3')";
        mysql_query($sql3);
    $sql4="insert into grupo values (null, $idgrupo, '$ced_alum4', '$nom4', '$ape4', '$turno4')";
        mysql_query($sql4);
    $sql5="insert into grupo values (null, $idgrupo, '$ced_alum5', '$nom5', '$ape5', '$turno5')";
        mysql_query($sql5);
    $sql6="insert into grupo values (null, $idgrupo, '$ced_alum6', '$nom6', '$ape6', '$turno6')";
        mysql_query($sql6);     
    }


//Botones Simples --------------------------------------------------------------------


if($boton=="Limpiar"){
        echo "<script>window.location='registro_alumno.php'</script>";  
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registro de grupos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">


<center><h1><font color="blue">Datos de Grupo</font></h1></center>

<table align="center" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="0" border="0">

<tr>
<td align="right"><Strong>Grupo Nro:</Strong></td> 
<td><input type="text" name="idgrupo" required placeholder="N° que identificará al grupo" value="<?PHP echo $idgrupo; ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="right"><strong>Carrera:</strong></td>
<td><input type="text" name="carrera" value="<?php echo $carrera;?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align="right"><strong>Periodo Academico:</strong></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="periodo" value="<?php echo $periodo;?>"></td>
</tr>

</table>

<p><label><h1><font color="blue"><center>Integrantes:</center></font></h1></label></p>
<center>
<p>
<label>Cédula: </label><input type="text" name="ced_alum" value="<?PHP echo $ced_alum; ?>"><input type="submit" name="boton1" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<label>Nombre: </label><input type="text" name="nom" value="<?PHP echo $nom; ?>">
<label>Apellido: </label><input type="text" name="ape" value="<?PHP echo $ape; ?>">
<label>Turno: </label><input type="text" name="turno" value="<?PHP echo $turno; ?>">
</p>

<p>
<label>Cédula: </label><input type="text" name="ced_alum2" value="<?PHP echo $ced_alum2; ?>"><input type="submit" name="boton2" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<label>Nombre: </label><input type="text" name="nom2" value="<?PHP echo $nom2; ?>">
<label>Apellido: </label><input type="text" name="ape2" value="<?PHP echo $ape2; ?>">
<label>Turno: </label><input type="text" name="turno2" value="<?PHP echo $turno2; ?>">
</p>

<p>
<label>Cédula: </label><input type="text" name="ced_alum3" value="<?PHP echo $ced_alum3; ?>"><input type="submit" name="boton3" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<label>Nombre: </label><input type="text" name="nom3" value="<?PHP echo $nom3; ?>">
<label>Apellido: </label><input type="text" name="ape3" value="<?PHP echo $ape3; ?>">
<label>Turno: </label><input type="text" name="turno3" value="<?PHP echo $turno3; ?>">
</p>

<p>
<label>Cédula: </label><input type="text" name="ced_alum4" value="<?PHP echo $ced_alum4; ?>"><input type="submit" name="boton4" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<label>Nombre: </label><input type="text" name="nom4" value="<?PHP echo $nom4; ?>">
<label>Apellido: </label><input type="text" name="ape4" value="<?PHP echo $ape4; ?>">
<label>Turno: </label><input type="text" name="turno4" value="<?PHP echo $turno4; ?>">
</p>

<p>
<label>Cédula: </label><input type="text" name="ced_alum5" value="<?PHP echo $ced_alum5; ?>"><input type="submit" name="boton5" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<label>Nombre: </label><input type="text" name="nom5" value="<?PHP echo $nom5; ?>">
<label>Apellido: </label><input type="text" name="ape5" value="<?PHP echo $ape5; ?>">
<label>Turno: </label><input type="text" name="turno5" value="<?PHP echo $turno5; ?>">
</p>
<p>
<label>Cédula: </label><input type="text" name="ced_alum6" value="<?PHP echo $ced_alum6; ?>"><input type="submit" name="boton6" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<label>Nombre: </label><input type="text" name="nom6" value="<?PHP echo $nom6; ?>">
<label>Apellido: </label><input type="text" name="ape6" value="<?PHP echo $ape6; ?>">
<label>Turno: </label><input type="text" name="turno6" value="<?PHP echo $turno6; ?>">
</p>

</center>


<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="7" border="0">
    <tr>
<td><div align="right"><input type="submit" name="boton" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-primary"></div></td>
<td><div align="right"><input type="submit" name="boton" value="Limpiar" class="btn btn-warning"></div></td>
<td><div align="right"><a href="http://localhost/sercom/menu3.php">Volver</a></div></td>
   </tr>
</table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```